# Web Scraping - Table Without Class or ID

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am working on a project which requires me to scrape a table from the following website - https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/energy/crude-oil/brent-crude-oil.settlements.html#tradeDate=03%2F31%2F2022

The problem I am facing is that the table doesnt seem to have classes when I inspect the elements.

I am new to web-scraping/BeautifulSoup and would appreciate any help I can get.

url:
https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/energy/crude-oil/brent-crude-oil.settlements.html#tradeDate=03%2F31%2F2022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually,the url aka table is dynamic and you can grab it with the help of selenium,bs4 and pandas as follows:

**Script:**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

url ="https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/energy/crude-oil/brent-crude-oil.settlements.html#tradeDate=03%2F31%2F2022"
    
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

df = pd.read_html(str(soup))[0]
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   Month  Open  High  Low  Last  Change  Settle  Est. Volume  Prior day OI
1   MAY 22     -     -    -     -    UNCH  113.45            0             0
2   JUN 22     -     -    -     -   -6.73  104.71            0             0
3   JLY 22     -     -    -     -   -5.91  102.73            0             0
4   AUG 22     -     -    -     -   -5.09  100.98            0             0
5   SEP 22     -     -    -     -   -4.34   99.43            0             0
6   OCT 22     -     -    -     -   -3.74   98.04            0             0
7   NOV 22     -     -    -     -   -3.29   96.75            0             0
8   DEC 22     -     -    -     -   -2.93   95.51            0             0
9   JAN 23     -     -    -     -   -2.62   94.35            0             0
10  FEB 23     -     -    -     -   -2.33   93.33            0             0
11  MAR 23     -     -    -     -   -2.04   92.53            0             0
12  APR 23     -     -    -     -   -1.78   91.78            0             0
```

Comment: This method throws an error:  `Document is empty` onl this line `df = pd.read_html(str(soup)[0])`

Comment: @pspythonm I've updated

Comment: @F.Hoque Appreciate your help!
Getting an error while executing the following line of code - driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
Error message: ‘Could not get version for google-chrome.Is google-chrome installed?’

Comment: You don't install anything related to selenium.you can just run the code.